# Workday as an ID provider for SAML authentication

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, workday-api

I have read the documentation which seems to lead me to believe that WD can act as a SAML ID provider. The use case is to be able to authenticate access for a valid Workday user into another website which uses SAML and does not use oAuth or social login etc.

Can you please let me know if this is possible and what documentation I would refer to please?

Comment: You can also use the protocol broker service so that SSO works with your applications which supports **OAuth**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a limited fashion. From a Workday [doc](https://doc.workday.com/reader/Z9lz_01hqDMDg6NSf7wCBQ/isnv08HWriJaS_fTijJoRA):

> You can create and edit SAML SSO links that use Workday as a SAML IdP
>   to sign in to other systems from Workday. Depending on your link
>   configuration, you can also pass contextual data to external systems.
>   Workday supports both SAML 1.1 and SAML 2.0.

Workday docs are published via a Workday Community. You must be a current Workday customer, partner or an employee to access it.

Comment: Thank you very much - yes I have access to the documentation - so I will reference there. I was thinking of using the Create SAML SSO Link Task...